# Cancel "Refresh all published content type"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type, timer-jobs, content-type-hub

I have SP 2013 and we clicked on "Refresh all published content type" at the site collection level (99% of content types come from the CTH).

I need to stop the job that's now queued up to run the next time the timer job triggers.  I haven't been able to find a PowerShell command or SQL script to address this.

I disabled the Content subscriber job for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dsiable the content subscriber timer job, restart SharePoint Timer service and then enable the content subscriber timer job.

[image]